# Is there any API to fetch metadata and headers only from Kafka without downloading the body

Tags: apache-kafka

- The problem: I need to do some analysis in the messages in some Kafka topics. The payload/body on those messages is very large. Thus causing a lot of resource usage in the consumer just to download the message and discard the payload. This is specially a problem with Java. The analysis only requires the headers and the metadata (timestamp, partition, etc)
- The question: Is there any API that allows only fetching the metadata and headers? Hopefully in Python or Java but I would even consider GO.

Answer (score 0):

There is not. Headers are stored as part of a Record, so therefore the entire body of a record must be consumed. There is no differences in client library since this is part of the Kafka TCP network spec.